# Passport failing with 404 - InternalOAuthError for GitHub why?

Tags: node.js, express, github, passport.js

I have passport working with Google, and Facebook.  I have attempted to add Github to add these credentials so I can do validated Github API calls.  So I simply added the same pattern I used to login using either Google or Facebook credentials.

BUT I see InternalOAuthError in the middle of my code after the auth callback has taken place from Github.  This happens when the nearly last line: 'return done(null, user.userData);' is called.  Attempting to debug interferes with the callbacks. SO  I am hoping that someone with greater clarity about passport can explain what I am doing wrong.

What is really strange is that I have already received the user profile from github and stored in in my database with 'user.update(db)', in the same way I do with google. Then the crash happens when I attempt to return by calling done(...).

Do I need to add something to my profile on github? or something else?
Or is this because I already have used passport much earlier to login using Google credentials.  Note that for Google, or Facebook, I have specified session: false. I have attempted this with both 'passport-github' and 'passport-github2'.

The code for clarity is:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var auth = require('../auth.service');

var router = express.Router();

router
  .get('/:user', passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: false
  }))

  .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: true
  }), auth.setTokenCookie);

module.exports = router;
```

and the corresponding passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github2').Strategy;
var monk_db = rekuire('server/monk_db');
var loggingAndErrors = rekuire('./loggingAndErrors');
var auth = require('../auth.service');
var config = require('../../config/environment');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var validateJwt = expressJwt({ secret: config.secrets.session });
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
var ObjectID = require("bson-objectid");

exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
      clientID: config.github.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.github.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.github.callbackURL,
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      //loggingAndErrors.logger.log(accessToken);
      var token = req.cookies.token;
      var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
      var user_id = decoded._id;
      var db = monk_db.getDb();
      var users = User.getUsers(db);
      users.findById(ObjectID(user_id), function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          loggingAndErrors.loggerError.log(err);
          return done(err);
        }
        //loggingAndErrors.logger.log(profile);
        user.github=profile._json
        user = User.newUser(user);
        user.update(db).onResolve(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            loggingAndErrors.loggerError.log(err);
            return done(err);
          }
          //loggingAndErrors.logger.log(user);
          loggingAndErrors.logger.log("calling done(err, user) for user_id:", user.userData._id);
          return done(null, user.userData);
        });
      });
    }
  ));
};
```

The crash is:

```
{ statusCode: 404,
data: '{"message":"Not\
Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}' }
GET /auth/github/callback?code=7c0c6dff81cdd9417301 500 945.444 ms - 674
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker2/node_modules/passport-github2/lib/strategy.js:118:21
at passBackControl (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker2/node_modules/passport-github2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker2/node_modules/passport-github2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:142:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, so here is what works for me.

Use [passport-github2](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github) and request access to the user's email address when authenticating:

```
passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] }));
```

There are other permissions that you may want to access at the same listed in the [GitHub OAuth documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).

Comment: Thanks VERY much for this hint.  This got me past this hurdle.  BUT not after allowing access, I find it throwing: Error: Failed to serialize user into session.  --- Perhaps that is also related to the permissions?  I will investigate, but if that is wrong, please advise.

Comment: Just realized that I needed to add:
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { done(null, user); });
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { done(null, user); });
Which solved the problem. ---- THANKS again.